# Inner Try Except in Python - How does the flow work?

Tags: python, except

We have inner try excepts like

```
try:

    try: (problem here)

    except: (goes here)

except: (will it go here) ??
```

Is that the currect flow of try excepts ? If an exception is caught inside for the outside try block , its an error or non - error ?

Comment: Moral of the story: *Don't* create blanket except clauses. Only catch *specific* exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not go in the second except, unless the first one raises an exception, too.

When you go in the `except` clause, you are pretty much saying "the exception is caught, I'll handle it", unless you re-raise the exception. For example, this construct can often be quite useful:

```
try:
    some_code()
    try:
        some_more_code()
    except Exception as exc:
        fix_some_stuff()
        raise exc
except Exception as exc:
    fix_more_stuff()
```

This allows you to have many layers of "fixing" for the same exception.

Answer (score 4):

It will not reach the outside `except`, unless you raise another exception within that one, like this:

```
try:
    try:
        [][1]
    except IndexError:
        raise AttributeError
except AttributeError:
    print("Success! Ish")
```

Unless the inner `except` block raises an exception fitting for the outer block, it will not count as an error.

Comment: Right , Exceptions Inside an Exception Goes to the Main Block

Answer (score 1):

The error will not hit the outer `Except`. You can test it like such:

```
x = 'my test'
try:
    try: x = int(x)
    except ValueError: print 'hit error in inner block'
except: print 'hit error in outer block'
```

This will only print `'hit error in inner block'`.

However, say you some other code after the inner `Try`/`Except` block, and this raises an error:

```
x, y = 'my test', 0
try:
    try: x = int(x)
    except ValueError: print 'x is not int'
    z = 10./y
except ZeroDivisionError: print 'cannot divide by zero'
```

This would print both `'x is not int'` AND `'cannot divide by zero'`.